# Setting Authorization Header when loading a script in index.html file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load a script from my server into my index.html file. For security reasons, access is restricted to the server, so only requests that have a valid access token in the header get processed, all others get denied with a status 401 "unauthorized" response. Loading the script in Postman works fine when I'm sending the access token in the header, but I don't know how I can add the access token when I load the script in my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://my-secured-server.com/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything like

```
<script type="text/javascript" headers="Authorization: Bearer 023q23..." src="https://my-secured-server.com/main.js"></script>
```

I need to protect my script from public access, so only making the path to the script public while keeping the rest of the server restricted is not a good solution for me.

Comment: How about send request and then get the result and append to header?

Comment: like this: `var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); request.open('GET', 'url', true); request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + oauthToken.access_token); request.onload = function (e) { append to header }`

Comment: Yes, probably the best solution, I'll try it.